# Python: Identify values changes in a column and count/label each group of a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that I am loading into a dataframe and I need to identify every time values change in a column, and label each group of adjacent rows with similar values AND have the count ignore rows that are not the values I care about.

Using this code (below) I can successfully identify and label the clusters but it fails to have the count only factor in the value I want (Desire 1).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

InputPath = r'C:\Users\YYYY\Desktop\File1.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(InputPath)
df[Result] = ((df['Mark'] != df['Mark'].shift(1)).cumsum()).where(df['Mark'] == 1)
```

Data:
data = {'Se

```
ries': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
        'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
         'Mark': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Series','Time','Mark'])
df

(Desire 2
```

) Additionally, how would I have it restart the count at 1 for each "Series", ensuring the count still increases with each new cluster as Time increases?

[image: Data Table, Result, and Desire]

Comment: `Desire1` is just `Result` divided by 2. (because it counts only every second group).

Comment: `Desire2` you can reach, by applying the formula for `Desire1` for each data frame for each of the Series separately. this is frequently done by `.groupby()` method.

Comment: can you give code for generating mini dataframe as this you show?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim great point on Desire 1! Also I've included the data for the dataframe in the question. 
Regarding your second comment, how would I do that - im new to all this and struggling to think of where I would include the .Groupby()

Comment: ah meanwhile I created. But I never understand why people putting a question here don't try to help those who wants to help them upfront. But hey you did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A'] * 9 + ['B'] * 9,
                            list(range(1, 10)) + list(range(1, 10)),
                            [0]*2 + [1]*2 + [0]*2 + [1]*2 + [0]*5 + [1]*1 + [0]*1 + [1]*2 + [0]*1]).transpose(), columns = ['Series', 'Time', 'Mark'])
df['Mark'] = [int(x) for x in df['Mark']]
df['Result'] = ((df['Mark'] != df['Mark'].shift(1)).cumsum()).where(df['Mark'] == 1)
df['Desire1'] = ((df['Mark'] != df['Mark'].shift(1)).cumsum() / 2).where(df['Mark'] == 1)

# make out of this a function, so that we can us it in following step:
def get_desire1(df):
    return ((df['Mark'] != df['Mark'].shift(1)).cumsum() / 2).where(df['Mark'] == 1)

df['Desire2'] = df.groupby('Series').apply(get_desire1).to_numpy().flatten() 

# or try the older solution:
df['Desire2'] = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([get_desire1(x[1]) for x in df.groupby('Series')])) 
# 'Desire2' is more a hack, because I hate the logic how aggregate in pandas works.
# For such stuff I use R more often ;) .
```

Then it looks like this:

```
   Series Time  Mark  Result  Desire1  Desire2
0       A    1     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
1       A    2     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
2       A    3     1     2.0      1.0      1.0
3       A    4     1     2.0      1.0      1.0
4       A    5     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
5       A    6     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
6       A    7     1     4.0      2.0      2.0
7       A    8     1     4.0      2.0      2.0
8       A    9     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
9       B    1     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
10      B    2     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
11      B    3     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
12      B    4     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
13      B    5     1     6.0      3.0      1.0
14      B    6     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
15      B    7     1     8.0      4.0      2.0
16      B    8     1     8.0      4.0      2.0
17      B    9     0     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Welcome, @NightLearner. I have simplified the last expression.

Comment: i just tried the new expression you posted and I'm getting the following error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'". Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Are you using python 2.x? - And anyway, after `df.groupby('Series').apply(get_desire1)` you don't have a dataframe object.

Comment: No, i'm using python 3, didn't realize that could be an issue

Comment: Look by `dir(df.groupby('Series').apply(get_desire1))` -> it will show you all avilable attributes and methods.

Comment: different python but especially different pandas versions cause issues.

Comment: ah ok, will look into this. For the time being i will continue to use the previous expression you wrote as i figure out the second one. thanks again!